# What is the right way to use an attribute directive to create conditional styling on an input element in an angular app?

Tags: angular

I am building an angular application and I want to use an attribute directive to style an input based on user input. I want this directive to apply a red border to the input, if the input is invalid. I have checked the docs on how to do this. [attribute directive docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and I have also checked the docs on ElementRef [ElementRef docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) The thing that makes me confused is that attribute directive docs says to do it by using ElementRef, and then in the ElementRef docs it says use this technique with extreme caution and only as a last resort. It seems weird that angular would provide a tool such as a directive that seems especially designed for this situation and then not tell you that it is not a good idea to use it and uncover that somewhere else in the docs. This brings me to my question. What is the right way to use an attribute directive to create conditional styling on an input element?

Comment: [ngClass] or [ngStyle]

Comment: Yeah Im aware that is also an option... I was curious about the directive logic approach because this directive is used everywhere so it would be nice to encapsulate the logic for that directive in the directive file...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: I want to say that I responded another thing that you are looking for. About why using ElementRef is "the last resort". I supouse that the main reason is for "compatibility" with another system (but don't ask me for these systems, because I don't find incompatibility with Cordova or any modern navigator). Another problem can be the security vulnerabilities. If you can access ElementRef, then you can acess document, then you can inject stricpt in the document..., but again I don't know how a code like nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = colorElementRef, can put your application on risk